# EditView is not Forcing User Input Correctly

Tags: java, android

After surfing through similar questions, I've come up with the following method to force the user to input a proper integer into an EditText. If they do not enter the correct integer, it displays the error message. Otherwise, it should open a new activity: "secondblock". I'm pretty certain that my condition is somehow wrong, since an input of 6 still forces the error message instead. If I remove the first if statement, it opens the other activity correctly, as expected. What could be wrong with this approach? Is it possibly since I'm utilizing toString()?

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdRth.jpg

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of adding screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

You're only getting the `value` from the `EditText` at the begining of your activity, while you need to read it every time from the `EditText`.

Move `String value = editText.getText().toString()` inside your `OnClickListener`.

And next time please just copy/paste your code here. It's easier to read that way.